# Как отловить любое событие изменения значения в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код проверяющий значение на валидность, и вот столкнулся с такой вот проблемой, когда ввожу значение вручную в `input` или когда вставляю значение из буфера, событие отлавливается и все работает, а вот когда выбираю значение из автокомплита, событие изменения значения в `input` не срабатывает, помогите пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно сделать.

```js
const nv = document.querySelector("input[name='nv']");
const button = document.querySelector("button.accept_modal");
nv.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var nvObj = {
    "nvAj": nv.value.toString()
  };
  console.log(e);
  $.ajax({
    url: "Cehst_nv",
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: nvObj,
    error: function(message) {},
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('checkNv').value = data;
      const checkNv = document.querySelector("input[name='checkNv']");
      if (nv.value !== checkNv.value) {
        $("#labelErr").text("Бла бла бла").css("display", "block");
        button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $("#labelErr").css("display", "none");
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    },
    beforeSend: function() {}
  });
});
```

Comment: Боюсь это не возможно сделать с помощью события. Один из вариантов самому создать событие. Например с помощью setInterval, проверять не изменились данные в поле

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через [потерю фокуса](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) поля сделать, помимо `input` евента

И\или добавить `focus mouse event'ы`, [вот тут все евенты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event), либо через таймер, что не есть гуд

```js
$('#form > input').on('input', ({currentTarget})=>{
    $(currentTarget).css('background', 'green');    
});

$('#form > input').on('focusout', ({currentTarget})=>{
    $(currentTarget).css('background', 'red');    
});

$('#form > input').on('focusin', ({currentTarget})=>{
    $(currentTarget).css('background', 'blue');    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="text input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password">
</form>
```

Comment: Та вот проблема в том, что если использовать focusout, то при выборе значения из автокомплита, фокус остается и оно не срабатывает

Comment: А еще не понятно почему не работает событие `change`

Comment: @Sorpok bump, добавил код

Answer (score 0):

В далеком 2011 году [писали](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548572/1430631) , что Chrome и IE при автодополнении генерируют событие `change`, а Opera c Firefox - `input`. Правда, Опера уже не та.

В примере ниже Chrome у меня сгенерировал оба события.

```js
const nv = document.querySelector("input[name='login']");
nv.addEventListener('change', monitorE);
nv.addEventListener('input', monitorE);
function monitorE(e) {
  console.log(e.type);
}
```

```html
<input name="login" type="text" autocomplete="on" />
```

Для проверки можно использовать `monitorEvents`, как рекомендуют в ответе (работает в devtools)